# Heavily downvoted questions disappearing from "Active" list

Tags: support, questions, downvotes, question-lists

I just noticed that a heavily downvoted question on [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) disappeared from [Meta's "Active" list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active).

One moment it was there, and after refreshing the page, it was gone.

The question isn't deleted as of this moment.
I suspect they're being filtered to only show questions scoring above `-10`(?)

Apparently they *do* show on the [questions list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions). Why is the homepage list filtered like that?

Comment: (I've purposely not linked the specific question, to avoid the meta effect)

Comment: This is by design. I think the cutoff is -6 or something like that (I know it's -3 on main sites).  Use the questions list, rather than the homepage, if you want to see all questions.

Comment: @yivi same, I think I also see the one you're on about

Comment: @Servy It's -8 on Metas.

Comment: @animuson Thanks.  I never used the homepage (for exactly this reason) so I didn't remember the exact cutoff.

Comment: @animuson I can see ones with `-13` and `-10` and such, are they still appearing because they have answers?

Comment: @George Are you on the questions list, rather than the homepage?  Also, caching could be at play here; the homepage doesn't update the list of questions in real time.

Comment: @Servy Homepage (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ just to be clear), I also have the new ui/tab interface so that could be why

Comment: Hmmm, I'm honestly not sure how the new nav is supposed to behave regarding this.

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue on the active tab, but I have the new nav tabs. Might be only for non-new nav.

Comment: I indeed have seen this happening around the same time, old nav.